# Continuum Approach to Modeling Cell Proliferation and Differentiation (PDE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

I'm new here so I hope this post is appropriate. I recently read in a bioengineering textbook about an approach to model cell proliferation and differentiation. They proposed the following partial differential equation:

$$ \frac{\partial X}{\partial t} +  \delta  \frac{\partial X}{\partial \lambda} =  \big( \mu - \alpha \big) X $$

$X$ is number of cells.
$t$ is time. 
$\lambda$ is the differentiation state, and can only have values between 0 and 1, which I will discuss below.

$\delta$, $\mu$, and $\alpha$ are differentiation rate, proliferation rate, and death rate, respectively, and have units of inverse time. I'll assume they are all constant for the time being.

I would be fine in solving this partial differential equation except for my interpretation of $\lambda$. In the population X, there are two kinds of cells, which I will call A and B. A transforms into B. Their sum is X.
$$A + B = X$$
If $\lambda = 0$, then X is entirely composed of A. If $\lambda = 1$, then X is entirely composed of B.

That is all my textbook tells me, but I would like to understand this further.

From my understanding, $\lambda$ could therefore be defined as:
$$\lambda = \frac{B}{X} = \frac{B}{A+B} $$

At first glance to me, $X$ should be a function of $t$ and $\lambda$, but if I'm saying that $\lambda$ is a function of A and B, does that mean that $X$ is only a function of time $t$?

Another question I have is about the implications of $\delta$. Does $\delta$ simply imply a transformation, or transformation and increase in numbers, based solely on the differentiation equation above.

I hope this question is not too biological for this forum. Thank you.

Comment: I think this is a very good and on-topic question about how to understand and interpret a particular differential equation. I don't know if it makes sense to think of $X$ in terms of A cells and B cells though -- in the original PDE, $X$ is both a function of $t$ and $\lambda$, so at any given time $t$ you have a different $X$ value at all values of $\lambda$ from $0$ to $1$. To me this suggests thinking of the situation as a *distribution* of cells with different $\lambda$'s, but I don't know if that is makes biological sense.

Comment: What's interesting is that the two terms on the left side of the PDE comprise the [advection equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection#Mathematics_of_advection), which one can interpret as saying that the cells move towards increasing $\lambda$ at a rate of $\delta$ per unit time. So if you initially had say $10$ cells at $\lambda=0$ and $5$ cells at $\lambda=0.1$, after time $t$ you'd have $10$ cells at $\lambda=\delta t$ and $5$ at $\lambda=0.1+\delta t$ (ignoring birth and death). If this sounds reasonable, I can write a answer explaining how this arises from the PDE later.

Comment: Hi Rahul! I think what you say makes perfect sense and might be what the author of my textbook meant by saying continuum. For a general solution to this PDE, I get $X(t,\lambda) =  e^{(\mu-\alpha)t} f(\lambda - \delta t)$, which fits with your explanation. What I am still struggling with understanding is how this PDE is a generality of the more simple exponential growth equation that would result if the system did not change over time with respect to $a$. I would appreciate any answer you would like to provide. Thank you!

Comment: @Rahul Sorry, Rahul. I did not notice I needed to write it this way to let you know of my response.